# JSON JS Array of Objects from Facebook FQL Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, facebook-fql

I've been pulling my hair out with this function. It's a function within a function which is why I think it's not returning anything, heres the code:

```
function getEventImageNormal(data) {
    $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/fql?access_token=" + access_token + "&q=SELECT pic FROM event WHERE eid=" + data, function(data){
        console.log(data.data[0].pic);
        return data.data[0].pic;
    });
}
```

The correct item, the URL of the image, is being set to the console log, but not being returned?

**If anyone is wondering why I'm not using `https://graph.facebook.com/object_id/picture` to get the events image, it's because this functionality is currently not working and the only method is to use FQL for event images.**

Comment: It's being returned from your anonymous function, but not from `getEventImageNormal`. In fact `getEventImageNormal` returns (`undefined`) well before that `console.log` executes.

Comment: You can't return what you want since the function returns before the data is available. You can call another function and pass the data in and you have to restructure your code to allow that. There's always `async: false` too but forget I even mentioned that because it locks up the web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `callback=?` parameter to your url to let remote url and jQuery know it is a `jsonp` call. If it is only json sent, it is against cross domain security policies and browser won't accept it into the DOM.

This is in addition to processing the data within the sucecss callback of request, due to asynchronous nature of ajax.

```
 var data=/* your value*/
 $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/fql?callback=?&access_token=" + access_token + "&q=SELECT pic FROM event WHERE eid=" + data, function(data){
 /* process data here*/

 })
```

Comment: That's spitting out an error to do with `not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: you need to investigate the API then and find out the protocol needed to receive jsonp. It must be jsonp, not json . Many API's provide json but that has to be retrieved with server code which doesn't have same constraints. I have never used facebook API for ajax.

Comment: FYI- there are lots of other questions in SO with same `callback=?` solution. Try moving it to the end of URL, shouldn't matter but is most common there

Comment: No, still no luck, 'undefined' is returned by the function.

Comment: perhaps you have to use the https. WIthout being able to see what's happening n my console is very hard to help more

Comment: I am using HTTPS. Not to worry.

Answer (score 2):

By default `getJSON()` performs asynchronous call.
You can call a function right within the success callback handler to treat the response.

```
$.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/fql?access_token=" + access_token + "&q=SELECT pic FROM event WHERE eid=" + data, function(data){
    console.log(data.data[0].pic);
    getResponse(data);
});

function getResponse(data) {
    // handle your data here.
}
```

Comment: This isn't working as data isn't defined and the getJSON is running immediately?

Comment: can you paste the logged data from the callback here? please comment out `getResponse()` function call before doing that.

Comment: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: data`

Comment: Apparently getJSON fires alright but doesn't return the data object you are expecting. Try changing `data` to `obj` in the callback function and log `obj` ONLY (without accessing any property) lets see the outcome.

Comment: Giving the error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'data.data[0]')